# How can python call a class that is never defined in the code?

Tags: python, python-import

I don't know if it is feasable to paste all of the code here but I am looking at the code in [this git repo](http://github.com/cloudkick/libcloud/tree/master).

If you look at the example they do:

```
ec2 = EC2('access key id', 'secret key')
```

...but there is no `EC2` class. However, it looks like in `libcloud\providers.py` there is a dict that maps the `EC2` to the `EC2NodeDriver` found in `libcloud\drivers\ec2.py`. The correct mapping is calculated by `get_driver(provider)`, but that method doesn't appear to be called anywhere.

I am new to python, obviously, but not to programming. I'm not even sure what I should be looking up in the docs to figure this out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`example.py` includes an `import` statement that reads:

```
from libcloud.drivers import EC2, Slicehost, Rackspace
```

This means that the `EC2` class is imported from the `libcloud.drivers` module. However, in this case, `libcloud.drivers` is actually a *package* (a Python *package* contains *modules*), which means that `EC2` should be defined in a file `__init__.py` in `libcloud/drivers/`, but it's not. Which means that in this specific case, their example code is actually wrong. (I downloaded the code and got an import error when running `example.py`, and as you can see, the file `libcloud/drivers/__init__.py` does not contain any definitions at all, least of all an `EC2` definition.)

Answer (score 0):

Checking out the libcloud\examples.py might be helpful.  I saw this:

```
from libcloud.drivers import EC2, Slicehost, Rackspace
```

The python 'import' statement brings in the class from other python module, in this case from the libcloud.drivers module.